# fsck on non-existent UUID on every boot

Tags: boot, fsck

I've got a problem with XUbuntu 19.04. On every boot, it runs a file system check that times out after 1:30 (killed by systemd) before the boot process continues.

It all started after I installed Debian 10.0 alongside (removed after only one attempt to boot, as it didn't recognize my video).

The tricky part:

The UUID that it's trying to check *does not exist*.

So I can't simply do a fsck on that drive once it's finished booting. There is no "trigger file" for "all" file system checks at the root.

I cannot do "tune2fs -l <...>" or "tune2fs -c" on the drive because the drive (the UUID) does not exist.

I already restored the partition to an image from before the issues began - and the file system checks continued. So it seems to be the partitions (why and how and what's changed?) and not Ubuntu, but... I also have Fedora installed on this computer and it boots without any strange file 
system checks just fine.

I also tried rebooting into single user mode - the drive's UUID does not exist there either.

A photo of the file system check: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpneN.jpg

How can I troubleshoot this? Obviously, I'd like the system to stop trying to fsck a non-existent drive.

EDIT:

```
cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=6d09fece-2e15-43ab-bf90-0ced66eb69df /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=9309-1800  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
#UUID=d516763d-bc3e-4dda-ab61-aa562dfaba18 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID=0433c6e7-07f7-4f2b-9da1-6d0756d79eba /home           f2fs    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=272f11a2-5157-432e-8a54-84758de52ef1 none            swap    sw              0       0

# Western Digital RE

# /mnt/archives
UUID=41b0e3d1-2f97-4d6e-916c-7286abb7cfae       /mnt/archives   ext4    defaults        0 2

# /mnt/documents
UUID=14EE-1640  /mnt/documents  vfat    uid=kman,gid=kman,iocharset=utf8,codepage=866 0 2

# Toshiba 

# /mnt/passport
UUID=b74afcc2-5e68-4922-ae6a-f745d6cfeb12   /mnt/passport   ext4    defaults,noauto 0 2
```

```
sudo lsblk -f | grep -v loop
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL         UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                                  
├─sda1      vfat                 9309-1800                             993.9M     3% /boot/efi
├─sda2      ext4   Frida         b60e174a-488e-46f5-b1f0-f57badcc9182                
├─sda4      ext4   Xandra        6d09fece-2e15-43ab-bf90-0ced66eb69df   47.1G    19% /
├─sda5      swap                 ec8b5ba8-b727-4d2b-b640-916109098845                
└─sda6      ext4   Android files 2af1d4f1-0da6-44e1-baf1-ab343080829e                
sdb                                                                                  
├─sdb1      vfat                 58A2-0240                                           
├─sdb2      ntfs   WinSystem     01D4A449338F8A80                                    
├─sdb3      ntfs                 01D4A449350624F0                                    
└─sdb4      ntfs   WinData       01D4A449F36DE360                                    
sdc                                                                                  
├─sdc1      ext4   Passport      b74afcc2-5e68-4922-ae6a-f745d6cfeb12                
└─sdc2      ntfs   Tanya         3D1341DE1547D4CB                                    
sdd                                                                                  
├─sdd1      vfat   DOCUMENTS     14EE-1640                              79.5G    20% /mnt/documents
├─sdd2      ext4   Archives      41b0e3d1-2f97-4d6e-916c-7286abb7cfae  392.8G    28% /mnt/archives
└─sdd3      ntfs   WinArchive    01D4A4BE55414770                                    
sde                                                                                  
sr0                                                                                  
nvme0n1                                                                              
├─nvme0n1p1 ext4   FHome         92e607fa-dda6-449f-9675-f1155f590e8e                
└─nvme0n1p3 f2fs   XHome         0433c6e7-07f7-4f2b-9da1-6d0756d79eba  174.5G     9% /home
```

Comment: Probably the UUID of your swap partition has been changed. Please add output of `cat /etc/fstab` and `lsblk -f | grep -v loop` to your question.

Comment: That's it - the ubiquitous swap partition!

UUID=272f11a2-5157-432e-8a54-84758de52ef1

Debian did format it as part of installation procedure. Not sure why Fedora wasn't confused, going to look into that next.

Comment: @mook765 please add a proper "answer" (not comment) so I can mark it as "accepted" and you can receive points for it.

Comment: I've reset the swap partition's UUID to what it was before with "mkswap -U <...>" and now everything is back to normal.

Fedora wasn't affected - it doesn't have its swap partition in fstab, probably just does "swapon --all".

Comment: If you changed the UUID of the swap partition to the former value, Debian will complain about the same thing, at least in one of the systems you should adapt `fstab`.

Comment: Re: If you changed the UUID of the swap partition to the former value, Debian will complain about the same thing

I already deleted the Debian partition. They still don't support my Intel i7's built-in video although the kernel patch has been available (in 4.20 series) for six months or so. But it didn't want to go easily it seems :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out in comments, the installation of Debian formatted an already  existing swap-partition and so changed it's UUID.

To find out what's going on the contents of `/etc/fstab` and the output of `lsblk -f | grep -v loop` should be viewed.

Both systems, Debian and Xubuntu use the same swap partition, both systems have a `fstab`-line regarding the swap partition. You have to use the same UUID in this`fstab`-line in both systems. So if you changed the UUID back to the former value, you have to adapt `/etc/fstab` in your Debian installation, otherwise Debian would be affected in the same way during boot.